# registrar en grupos /arreglos javascript

Tags: javascript

Como puedo hacerle si quiero registrar a alumnos pero que solo puedan estar en un grupo?

```js
 gpoalumno=prompt("Ingrese el grupo \n 1.11191 \n2.1192 \n3.21191 \n4.21192")
     if(gpoalumno==1){
    do{
      ya_esta=0; 
   aux_idalumno=prompt("Ingrese ID del alumno"+"\n"+"Registro no.: "+renglon);
    for(x=0;x<=renglon;x++){
      if(aux_idalumno==id_alumno[x]){
        ya_esta=1;
        alert("ID ya Registrado");
      }
    }
  }while(ya_esta!==0);
  if(ya_esta!=1){ 
    id_alumno[renglon]=aux_idalumno; 
    
   do{
      ya_estanombre=0; 
   aux_nombrealumno=prompt("Ingrese su nombre completo");
   //validar a mayusculas
    for(x=0;x<=renglon;x++){
      if(aux_nombrealumno==nombrealumno[x]){
        ya_estanombre=1;
        alert("Nombre ya Registrado");
      }
    }
   
   if(ya_estanombre===0){
     nombrealumno[renglon]=aux_nombrealumno;
     alert("Alumno registrado \n ID: "+id_alumno[renglon]+"Nombre:"+nombrealumno[renglon].toUpperCase());
   }
```

Comment: La relación es ¿Alumno N - 1 Grupo? Quieres evitar que un alumno esté en más de un grupo, ¿cierto?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema con tu código? ¿Te da algún mensaje de error?